# Pseudo-Stream flv from other server, using a local html file

Tags: html, flash, external, flv, pseudo-streaming

Is it possible to pseudo-stream a flv video on an external server that only allows pseudo-streaming if you watch the video from a website hosted on this external server? 
I want to access the flv file using a html file on my pc. (Not using another website.)
I tried it using the flowplayer, but it wasn't pseudo-streaming (I couldn't seek behind the point in the video that wasn't already downlaoded).

Btw if I download the whole sourcecode of the external site and try to run it in my browser the player stays black and doesn't do anything.

If it is not possible, it would be nice if you would explain me why. :)

And yes I have permission to do this.

edit:
Sorry, I'm soo stupid. -.-
I used a flowplayer configuration that didn't allow pseudo-streaming.
The example on this site works great: http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/streaming/

Answer (score 1):

So in order to "Seek" via flash or html 5, you need something called a Moov Atom, you could think of the Moov Atom much as you would a Key Frame in a Standard Mpeg 2 file.

If you have the Moov Atoms (you can apply these with atomic parsley or other encoders - Just Google how to add Moov atoms to flv.)  you will then be able to seek from atom position to atom position. [Much like when you seek an mpeg it moves from keyframe to keyframe]

I have tried to keep this answer generalist, as I don't think you really want to know all the finer details of the flv container or it's playback.

Hope this helped.

Cheers
Craig

Comment: But I don't have access to the flv file(s). I want to pseudo-stream them just the way the files are at the moment. Since I can already seek to whatever point I want when I access the file through a flash video player on website that is hosted on the same server as the flv files, I think that the Moov Atoms are already in the flv?

Comment: If the moov atoms are present then seeking should work. If not then they wont. I steam about 7.1TB of flv content a day, the files themselves are on a different set of servers than the site and the player. Seeking should be possible if the files are correct.